# Enable touchpad even if in acpi=off [ASUS X540UP]

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, touchpad, asus, acpi

I have an ASUS X540UP 1TB hdd(Windows) & 250GB ssd(Ubuntu 18.04).

I installed ubuntu via USB Flash Drive at first installation process was okay and touchpad is working.

But when booting to installed Ubuntu OS I had difficulties, hence resorted to adding `acpi=off` in GRUB file. Now I use Ubuntu with external mouse.

I would like to use the touchpad, but when removing `acpi=off` I can boot to login screen and touchpad is working but after logging in it freezes (purple screen). Is there a way to make touchpad work even if `acpi=off` is added. Thanks